# How to correctly delete all current sessions in production Rails 7 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

Let's say we have to urgently reset all sessions in Rails 7 app (e.g. after changing primary IDs). How to do it correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are stored at the client so you cannot delete them, you can only invalidate them and I know of two ways how to do that.

### 1. Change `secret_key_base`

The session cookie is encrypted using `secret_key_base` of the application so changing it will invalidate all previously created sessions. Although this looks fast and easy I would avoid it because it may also break something else that uses `secret_key_base` to sign or encrypt other data.

### 2. Add version to your session

Add a new key holding a version to your session. It can be a version of your application or a version of the session itself. Then you can implement whatever logic you want. First reject any session that has no version. Later you can do something like allow sessions from previous patch versions and reject sessions from previous minor and major versions.

Comment: changing secret_key_base worked well for me. Thanks